# Composing IObservables and cleaning up after registrations

Tags: system.reactive

I have some code in a class that takes `FileSystemWatcher` events and flattens them into an event in my domain:

*(Please note, the `*AsObservable` methods are extensions from elsewhere in my project, they do what they say .)*

```cs
            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(ConfigurationFilePath);

            ChangeObservable = Observable
                .Merge(
                    watcher.ChangedAsObservable().Select((args) =>
                    {
                        return new ConfigurationChangedArgs
                        {
                            Type = ConfigurationChangeType.Edited,
                        };
                    }),
                    watcher.DeletedAsObservable().Select((args) =>
                    {
                        return new ConfigurationChangedArgs
                        {
                            Type = ConfigurationChangeType.Deleted,
                        };
                    }),
                    watcher.RenamedAsObservable().Select((args) => 
                    {
                        return new ConfigurationChangedArgs
                        {
                            Type = ConfigurationChangeType.Renamed,
                        };
                    })
                );

            ChangeObservable.Subscribe((args) =>
            {
                Changed.Invoke(this, args);
            });
```

Something that I'm trying to wrap my head around as I'm learning are best practices around naming, ownership and cleanup of the `IObservable` and `IDisposable` returned by code like this.

So, some specific questions:

- Is it okay to leak `IObservable`s from a class that creates them? For example, is the property I'm assigning this chain to okay to be `public`?
- Does the property name `ChangeObservable` align with what most people would consider best practice when using the .net reactive extensions?
- Do I need to call `Dispose` on any of my subscriptions to this chain, or is it safe enough to leave everything up to garbage collection when the containing class goes out of scope? Keep in mind, I'm observing events from `watcher`, so there's some shared lifecycle there.
- Is it okay to take an observable and wire them into an event on my own class (`Changed` in the example above), or is the idea to stay out of the native .net `event` system and leak my `IObservable`?

Other tips and advice always appreciated!

---

Comment: Please keep in mind that the garbage collector does **not** call `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it okay to leak IObservables from a class that creates them? For
>   example, is the property I'm assigning this chain to okay to be
>   public?

Yes.

> Does the property name ChangeObservable align with what most
>   people would consider best practice when using the .net reactive
>   extensions?

Subjective question. Maybe `FileChanges`? The fact that it's an observable is clear from the type.

> Do I need to call Dispose on any of my subscriptions to
>   this chain, or is it safe enough to leave everything up to garbage
>   collection when the containing class goes out of scope?

The `ChangeObservable.Subscribe` at the end could live forever, preventing the object from being garbage collected if the event is subscribed to, though that could also be your intention. Operator subscriptions are generally fine. I can't see the code for your `ChangedAsObservable` like functions. If they don't include a `Subscribe` or an event subscription, they're probably fine as well.

> Keep in mind,
>   I'm observing events from watcher, so there's some shared lifecycle
>   there.

Since `FileWatcher` implements `IDisposable`, you should probably use `Observable.Using` around it so you can combine the lifecycles.

> Is it okay to take an observable and wire them into an event on
>   my own class (Changed in the example above), or is the idea to stay
>   out of the native .net event system and leak my IObservable?

I would prefer to stay in Rx. The problem with event subscriptions is that they generally live forever. You lose the ability to control subscription lifecycle. They're also feel so much more primitive. But again, that's a bit subjective.

Comment: Subjective answers are okay and 100% what I'm after here.  Thank you for offering your insights!